# Gradually rendering parametric surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I want to gradually render the surface like this
[image] [image]
For parametric curves, it can be drawn gradually in the following way. After generating a graph, then extract the data for plotting, avoid some duplicate calculations, this should be faster.

```
plt = ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)];
len = Cases[plt, Line[x_, rest_] :> Length[x], -1][[1]];
Manipulate[plt /. Line[x_, rest_] :> Line[Take[x, i], rest], {i, 1, len, 1}]
```

For parametric surfaces, my current attempt, the mesh was not generated in the way I expected, I think it's a little slow, because there are a lot of repeated calculations. Do you have a good way?

```
With[{surf = {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), r Sin[t/2]},
  opts = Sequence[Axes -> False, Mesh -> {4, 15}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3.43, 4.4}, {-4.12, 4.12}, {-1.12, 1.12}}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> Black, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 300]},
 Manipulate[Row@{
    ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, u}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#5] &), opts],
    ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, u}, MeshShading -> {{Cyan, Orange}, {Orange, Cyan}},
 opts]}, {u, 0.001, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I tried setting `ColorFunctionScaling->False` and manually scaling the range based on the max for `u`.  Also I set `MeshFunctions` manually to not simply subdivide up to `u`, but up to `2Pi` -- unfortunately the `Floor` function results in very wonky divisions.

```
With[{surf = {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), r Sin[t/2]},
opts = Sequence[Axes -> False, Mesh -> {4, 15}, 
PlotRange -> {{-3.43, 4.4}, {-4.12, 4.12}, {-1.12, 1.12}}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Black, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 300,
    (* modified *) ColorFunctionScaling->False,MeshFunctions->{#4&,Floor[16#5/Pi]&}
]},
Manipulate[Row@{
ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, u}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[
    (* modified *) #5/(2Pi)
] &), opts],
ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, u},
MeshShading -> {{Cyan, Orange}, {Orange, Cyan}},opts]}, {u, 0.001, 2 Pi}]]
```

So the hack I recommend instead is to plot with `{t,0,2Pi}` and simply set `surf={0,0,0}` if `t>u`, i.e.

```
With[{
  surf=If[t<=u,{Cos[t](3+r Cos[t/2]),Sin[t](3+r Cos[t/2]),r Sin[t/2]},{0,0,0}],
opts=...]
```

[image: animation]

Answer (score 4):

- We draw the full surface and use `RegionFunction` to cut the surface by `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, t <= u]`.
- We manual set the `Mesh` by `Mesh -> {Subdivide[-1, 1, 4 + 1], Subdivide[0, 2 π, 15 + 1]}` instead of `{4,15}`.

```
surf = {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
  r Sin[t/2]};
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> 60,
   MaxRecursion -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Subdivide[-1, 1, 4 + 1], Subdivide[0, 2 π, 15 + 1]}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[v/(2 π)]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, t <= u], Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.43, 4.4}, {-4.12, 4.12}, {-1.12, 1.12}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> 300], {u, $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

- For the second gif, we use the same way.

```
surf = {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
  r Sin[t/2]}; 
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
  Mesh -> {Subdivide[-1, 1, 4 + 1], Subdivide[0, 2 π, 15 + 1]}, 
  MeshShading -> {{Cyan, Orange}, {Orange, Cyan}}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, t <= u], Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.43, 4.4}, {-4.12, 4.12}, {-1.12, 1.12}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> 300], {u, $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

- Integrate the animation as OP.

```
With[{surf = {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
    r Sin[t/2]}, 
  opts = Sequence[Axes -> False, 
    Mesh -> {Subdivide[-1, 1, 4 + 1], Subdivide[0, 2 π, 15 + 1]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-3.43, 4.4}, {-4.12, 4.12}, {-1.12, 1.12}}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> Black, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    ImageSize -> 300]}, 
 Manipulate[
  Row@{ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
     ColorFunction -> (Hue[#5/(2 π)] &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, opts, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, t <= u]], 
    ParametricPlot3D[surf, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
     MeshShading -> {{Cyan, Orange}, {Orange, Cyan}}, opts, 
     RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z, r, t}, t <= u]]}, {u, $MachineEpsilon, 
   2 Pi}]]
```

[image]